# Thermal camera reference device

Tags: resistors, temperature, thermal-camera

I'm trying to find a device that can act as a reference for a thermal camera, but everything I find is always some tens-of-thousands-of-dollars blackbody device that is accurate to within 0.01 K. I have been unable to find anything cheap - for my purposes, I simply need a device that can be accurate to within a quarter of a degree or so. Is it possible to build such a device (or buy one that isn't several thousand dollars)?

Essentially, I'm just trying to get something (i.e. a resistor) to reliably be about 35 degrees Celsius with a .25 degree margin of error or so

Comment: what if you get a beaker, paint it black, and fill it with pure boiling water, with a heating element that doesn't touch the sides (or something like that)?

Comment: @BeB00 that might work, but I'm trying to get the camera calibrated around 35 degrees C, so a 100 deg calibration might not be ideal. I've edited this into the question

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get an RTD use that to calibrate some object?

Comment: @DKNguyen technically I could put a constant current through a resistor and get it to about 35 degrees then use an RTD to measure the temperature of the resistor, but I would rather be able to have an independent circuit I could power on, then measure the temperature of the device with the thermal camera and compare that value to the known value (because the thermal camera is attached to an android app and trying to take input from and RTD would complicate things greatly)

Answer (score 2):

I did this for work. It's neither pretty nor hard, but when you layer multiple requirements on it the cost goes up significantly.

First your surface needs to be similar to the emission profile you want. So- flat, black, high temperature matte spray paint. You can use VantaBlack or other super-black too, so long as the emission profile meets specs. Caliper paint was cheap.

I used copper. Why copper? Large heat reservoir when brought up to temperature. It was large, 18x18, with 2" hidden around the edges. It weighed ... well, don't drop it. It was machined / ground flat which the machinists hated for destroying their bits. I can't remember what it was polished to before we messed up the surface with the paint.

PTC heating elements. Several. You'll have to do the math to figure out how many and what their leakage rate is, but get the same lot codes or batch if you can. You'll want them to produce about the same amount of heat, but it isn't as critical because you'll be using PID control loops to keep them at about the same wattage rates.

Third, insulation. The more the better. You're going to overhang the edge of the copper plate all the way around, so (depending on how big you need) you'll need to adjust your insulation and thickness. Personally I would recommend the ceramic material, as it can be painted/hardened and once used with hardener it won't go anywhere. If I could do it again I think I'd totally be into getting aerogel. Why? Because why not! It's extremely effective and cool looking.

Oh, are you going to move it? Then you'll need to have the whole unit transportable, as the copper alone is going to weigh a hundred pounds. So some sort of wheels but more importantly all of the 'mounting points' are going to suck heat away from the copper plate, so you'll have to find a way to mount it with very thin, very strong, very thermally resistant material. Ceramic works best if you can afford it and/or have access to a shop that can print it.

You'll also need lots of PT100/RTDs. You'll also want some K-type as well, as they may drift but you'll have your PT100s to stay in reference to. The more accurate the better, so have your metrology group run the numbers down for you.

And at this point you have a multi channel heating block with a dozen + PID control loops heating the back of the plate, insulated, with the heat only able to go out the front. The PT100s feed back to you to see what the plate is looking like from the back. With enough material it'll slowly oscillate but the thermal 'pulse' of heat moving through it gives a pretty steady window, especially if you put controller interfaces on the front of it (around the front and insulated).

Basically your controllers in the back keep the back at a steady state of temperature, and the controllers at the front keep the front whereever you want it by letting the back temperature go up.

You'll do this in a controlled room/temperature with no air movement. A quarter degree doesn't sound like much, but the air alone drifting over the surface can cool that rapidly.

In short, it really is a lot of work. If you want to be within 2 degrees, that's far easier. But you still have lots of math and testing to do to get it right, or a lot of extra cost over-designing it so that you can (eventually) turn off the hardware you don't need to use anymore.

OR.... make a very small unit that you can mash your camera up in front of (instead of a large one) and use RTDs around it to measure and interpolate the center value, after correcting for cosine falloff.

Comment: Why did you use expensive copper and not something like steel which has a higher heat capacity?

Comment: Honestly? No idea at this point. When we were setting it up we needed to move as much heat as possible through it, so I can't recall why. Looking at the thermal emissivity coefficients though that probably would have been cheaper. Of course getting it to temp might have been harder or longer. Sigh too many years.

Comment: Thermal conductivity of steel is a lot worse than copper but it didn't seem to me like it would matter in this case.

Comment: The unit I worked on had to be used outdoors / in a hangar, from WAAAAYYYY across the way.... so it was hit or miss. Steel isn't very good at conducting heat. Probably was to get it as hot as possible as fast as possible and deal with all the cooling effects. Sadly, I really don't remember :(

Comment: Yeah if speed mattered then copper.

Comment: An airplane idling costs a lot of money. So does having the pilot stand around ;P The intern is cheap though.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally look into a hole into a chamber painted black on the inside and with isothermal walls.

A thick aluminum plate painted flat black and shaded on the sides, temperature controlled to the target temperature might be close enough.

Comment: Yes, a chamber with a hole will help compensate for an imperfect absorption percentage. Some PhDs in Physics taught me this trick.

Answer (score 0):

How about just heating a diode, with metal foil plates soldered to the TWO leads, to radiate the heat.

The diode measures its own temperature. If the foil plates are well insulated, there will be little heat escaping the system, and the diode/plates are iso_thermal.